# Set theory exercise involving setminus and empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set. $A\subset X$ and $B\subset X$.

> $A\subseteq B$ iff $A\setminus B = \emptyset$

Attempted proof - Suppose $A\subseteq B$ and $x\in (A\setminus B)$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ since $A\subseteq B$. So, $x\in A\cap B$ which implies that $A\cap B\subseteq B$. Note we can write $$A = (A\cap B) \cup (A\setminus B)$$ then clearly we have $A\setminus B = \emptyset$

Conversely, suppose $A\setminus B = \emptyset$ then if $x\notin B$ then $x\in A\setminus B = \emptyset$, so $x\in B$ thus $A\subseteq B$

Not really sure where to go from here. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first part is correct.  If $x \notin B$ then $x \in A \setminus B$.  But $A \setminus B$ is empty, so $x \in B$.

Comment: @Paul Is the first part of my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, the first part is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your proof, showing that $A \subseteq B \implies A \setminus B = \emptyset$, can be simplified (though the essential idea is correct). Assume that there exists an $x \in A \setminus B$; $x \in B$ by the definition of subsets, but $x \not \in B$ from the definition of set difference. This is a contradiction, so there can't exist any $x \in A \setminus B$, which means $A \setminus B = \emptyset$.

To show that $A \setminus B = \emptyset \implies A \subseteq B$, assume that $A \setminus B = \emptyset$, but $A \not \subseteq B$. This means there is some $y \in A$ with $y \not \in B$. You should be able to show that this implies $y \in A \setminus B$, which contradicts the assumption that $A \setminus B = \emptyset$. Thus, $A \subseteq B$ by contradiction.